# Increase width on Mailchimp signup box using Wordpress divi theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a client's website using the Wordpress Divi theme https://www.nationwidescents.com/  I didn't use it but I've ran into a few troubles customizing things that disagree with this theme (has anyone else had that issue?)

So in the footer on the bottom right, I'm trying to add the mailchimp signup box. It's there now but I want the width to be wider (100%). I've tried in-line css on the embed code and also trying these class tags with the width CSS in the additional CSS:

```
.input#mce-EMAIL.email
#mce-EMAIL.email
.email
#mce-EMAIL 
.mc_embed_signup_scroll
```

Still haven't cracked it. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try:

```
#mc_embed_signup input#mce-EMAIL {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The thing with your selector is that they all match, BUT there is already a selector with a "width: 50%" attribute: **#mc_embed_signup input.email**

This selector overrides your selectors and therefore the 50% remained. You could use [this calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) to check or read up on CSS specificity.
Hope this helps!